# SQL query to count IDs and display a 0 on empties within a date range

Tags: sql, join, count

Im sorry as I know this type of question has been asked a lot, but the posts I am seeing dont seem to fit quite what I am trying to do or make a difference, its a simple solution in that I have one table which stores a type ID and a date saved and then another table with that type ID and the type name.

What I want is so that it will display all the saved types within a set date range but display a 0 count rather than that type not display at all. If I run my query as just a count it does exactly what I want

```
SELECT     dbo.RequestType.Type, COUNT(dbo.Requests.RequestType) AS Count
FROM         dbo.RequestType LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Requests ON dbo.RequestType.TypeID = dbo.Requests.RequestType
GROUP BY dbo.RequestType.Type
```

But if I put a date range on it like so:

```
SELECT     dbo.RequestType.Type, COUNT(dbo.Requests.RequestType) AS Count
FROM         dbo.RequestType LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Requests ON dbo.RequestType.TypeID = dbo.Requests.RequestType
WHERE     (dbo.Requests.DateSaved BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-03-30 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY dbo.RequestType.Type
```

Then any 0 counts aren't displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Why you are converting dates? have you tried just doing `BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-03-30'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that anything in the `WHERE` clause will be checked against the records, so if it refers to a table on the *right* side of your *left* outer join, that undoes the outer-ness of the join. Just move that clause into the `ON`.

```
SELECT     dbo.RequestType.Type, 
  COUNT(dbo.Requests.RequestType) AS Count
FROM dbo.RequestType 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Requests 
ON dbo.RequestType.TypeID = dbo.Requests.RequestType
  AND     (dbo.Requests.DateSaved 
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-03-30 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY dbo.RequestType.Type
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, will do a bit more testing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get list of Distinct Request Types first, then left join on that.

```
WITH D AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT dbo.RequestType.Type
    FROM dbo.RequestType
)
SELECT     D.Type, COALESCE(COUNT(dbo.Requests.RequestType),0) AS Count
FROM D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RequestType ON D.Type=dbo.RequestType.Type
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Requests ON dbo.RequestType.TypeID = dbo.Requests.RequestType AND (dbo.Requests.DateSaved BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-03-30 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY dbo.RequestType.Type
```